# The web browser.open() function keeps opening youtube page only when the given url is different

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

```
if 'open youtube' or 'youtube' or 'open yt' in data1:
         webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/')
    elif 'twitter' or 'open twitter' in data1:
        webbrowser.open('https://twitter.com/home/')
    elif 'seven' or'play seven' in data1:
        webbrowser.open('https://youtu.be/QU9c0053UAU/')
    elif 'open spotify' or 'spotify' in data1:
        webbrowser.open('https://open.spotify.com/')
```

data1 is where the speech to txt module saves the entry

Any solution would be helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.